# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[customType]

Tags: c#, generics, arraylist

I have ArrayList which contains 4 items. each item is of type `List<object>` . I am trying to get  first item from ArrayList using below code. but it throws error

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CustomType]

calling code  -

```
ArrayList arrayList = BusinessLayer.GetData();
List<CustomType> tempList = (List<CustomType>)arrayList[0];
```

called code logic -

```
if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "EXEC SP_GET_DATA @id";
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var customTypeList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
                            .ObjectContext
                            .Translate<object>(reader)
                            .ToList();

                    arrayList.Add(customTypeList);
        
                   reader.NextResult();

                   var customType2List = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
                            .ObjectContext
                            .Translate<object>(reader)
                            .ToList();

                    arrayList.Add(customType2List);
              }
```

I am returning arraylist and want to get data back at calling code. I don't want to use model in called code. I understand that, we can use model at called code but I have to verify whether using ArrayList, can we get data back? I hope I explained clearly.

here I am trying to cast `List<object>` from ArrayList to `List<CustomType>`

Comment: Not sure but you can get the base type of an object using reflection.

Comment: `var tempList = arrayList[0].Cast<CustomType>().ToList();`

Comment: @SandeepJadhav blindly using `object` when you know the type is almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes each item in arraylist is of type List<object> and I want to cast every item to their respective generic type. All items in arraylist are of different type .

Comment: @SSD So repeat `arrayList[index].Cast<OtherCustomType>().ToList();` for indices 1 through 3 with their respectie target types to create the 3 other lists

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it doesn't work. `'Queryable.Cast<TResult>(IQueryable)'` is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: *All items in arraylist are of different type* - no, you've just said they are all `List<objects>`s

Comment: @SSD Wrong method, you want [`Enumerable.Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Cast__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_). You might need to cast the arraylist item explicitly first: `((List<object>)arrayList[index]).Cast<OtherCustomType>().ToList();`

Comment: It's 2021. "Business Layer" wasn't even a thing when ArrayList became obsolete- how did you find yourself here?! Is there anything you can do to rewrite this code to be more developer friendly? An arraylist full of list<object> is rather a strong code smell

Comment: @CaiusJard you are right. while placing data in arraylist, I casted each item of differenttype to List<object> as all items are List , each of differentType. but now I have to get data back

Comment: If you can't, instead please show us a screenshot of the Locals window showing us your fully expanded arraylist and each element within also fully expanded, ensure we can see the data type on the screenshot and tell us what you actually exactly want as a result

Comment: *while placing data in arraylist, I casted to each item* - so this really is code you wrote in 2021? I think it'd be worth showing us that code so we can suggest how to rewrite it using constructs from modern .net - but first show us the requested screenshot

Comment: @CaiusJard I edited my question and added code logic for reference. you can check now

Comment: How are you getting on with adding that screenshot I requested? To add a shot, debug the code until you have this array list in scope, open the locals window, expand the array list to show its contents (it's about 4 items?) which are lists of object, then expand each list so we can see a good representative sample of the object types there in. Open the windows snipping tool, capture the region, come to SO, edit your question and press Ctrl V- the Ctrl c is implicitly done by snipping tool I think.. the image should auto attach as an imgur link

Comment: That's not the only thing wrong with this code: you should be disposing your connection and command with `using`, and if so it makes no sense to check `if (connection.State == Closed)`. You should call stored procedures with just `SP_GET_DATA` as the `CommandText`, and `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. You should specify parameter types and lengths explicitly

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly cast back to List of Object first. Then use Cast to the custom type.

```
ArrayList arrayList = new();

arrayList.Add(new List<object>() { new Person() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "NewHart"} });

List<Person> tempList = ((List<object>)arrayList[0]).Cast<Person>().ToList();

Console.WriteLine(tempList[0].FirstName);
Console.ReadLine();

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I get the same Error, only now it is  Unable to cast object of type 'MyObject[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.'

Comment: @RickRunowski - Are you trying to cast an array to a list? Those are two different types. It sounds like you should convert it using `.ToList()`.

Comment: Yeah, at the time the .ToList() was failing also... I don't recall  now how I got it working, but there was something wrong with my object.  Thanks!